# Cron not working

Tags: php, cron

I have created for cron do run at 1am as follow.
0 1 * * *
it was not working, but when tried like 0 13 * * * it's working normally.
Please suggest solutions for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Both of those cron times will work, something else is causing you issues if the script is not running.  More information is required.

Answer (score 1):

Create a test page like `test.php`

write the code below to your `test.php`

```
<?
echo "Current server time: " . date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Eucla'); //List of time zone http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
echo "and My locale time: " . date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
?>
```

Now check and calculate the deference of time from your local time with server time and set the correct time in corn job

eg: Current server time: 21-08-2018 00:35:25 and My locale time: 21-08-2018 12:35:36 then server time 12hrs less from your local time. So you should set corn job 12hrs less from your require time.

Comment: Hi,here is my result.it's fine. I don't know what is the problem.Current server time: 21-08-2018 15:22:09and My locale time: 21-08-2018 15:22:09

Comment: So if you want to run script at 1pm you should set `0 13 * * *` or for 1am you should `0 01 * * *`.